# No response from the server error in ejabberd server

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

Now I am working with XMPP-chat for Android using ejabberd server.

When I am trying to connect to the server, it shows an error. But it works fine in openfire server.

I am using `smack library`.

Error log is given below:

> 04-21 20:34:16.824: I/XMPPChatDemoActivity(1929): [SettingsDialog] Connected to 10.0.2.2
>       04-21 20:34:21.932: E/XMPPChatDemoActivity(1929): Failed to log in as test3@eworks.com
>       04-21 20:34:21.932: E/XMPPChatDemoActivity(1929): No response from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution how to connect to gtalk and jabber.org with Smack 3.1.0:

Code for GTalk:

```
ConnectionConfiguration cc = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(cc);
try {
     connection.connect();

     // You have to put this code before you login
     SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);

     // You have to specify your gmail addres WITH @gmail.com at the end
     connection.login("some.account@gmail.com", "password", "resource");

     // See if you are authenticated
     System.out.println(connection.isAuthenticated());

} catch (XMPPException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

For jabber.org here is the code:

```
ConnectionConfiguration cc = new ConnectionConfiguration("jabber.org", 5222, "jabber.org");
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(cc);
try {
     connection.connect();

     // You have to put this code before you login
     SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);

     // You have to specify your Jabber ID addres WITHOUT @jabber.org at the end
     connection.login("your.jabber", "password", "resource");

     // See if you are authenticated
     System.out.println(connection.isAuthenticated());

} catch (XMPPException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

With this code i can now connect to my local ejabberd and openfire server. I hope this will solve your problems.